# How to secure Web API with Auth0 without exposing ClientId & ClientSecret to client?

Tags: api, auth0

I am creating a new .Net Core Web API that is consumed by a new React client-side app. Both the client-side app and the Web API are on different hosts and protected by Auth0. I set up both the client-side app and the Web API in Auth0, and then I created a machine-to-machine app in Auth0 to be able to communicate with the Web API silently (without a user interface). The security flow works like this:

- User tries to access client-side app.
- User is re-directed to Auth0 to provide credentials.
- Auth0 authenticates the credentials and returns user info (including user ID + access token) to client-side app.
- Client-side app stores user info in local storage for future use until it expires.
- Any calls to 3rd party APIs are routed through my own Web API, so 3rd party API keys are sitting in a safe place on the server, not on the client-side.
- User accesses a page that requires a call to my Web API but we don't have an access token for my Web API yet.
- Client-side app reads the ClientId & ClientSecret (hard-coded values) from .env file and makes a POST request to Auth0 to fetch an access token for my Web API (this is Auth0's recommended way of getting the access token for the Web API silently except they don't specify where the ClientId & ClientSecret would be stored).
- Auth0 returns an access token for my Web API.
- Client-side app stores the Web API access token in local storage for future use until it expires.
- Client-side app invokes my Web API with newly acquired access token as the bearer token in the header.
- Web API receives the access token, authenticates with Auth0 and fulfills the request.

All of the above is working for me but I am concerned about storing the Auth0 ClientSecret of my Web API in the client-side app. Although it is not visible on the screen or in a cookie anywhere, any capable user would be able to get at it by inspecting the network traffic.

Many people on the Internet seem to be fine with storing 3rd party API keys in .env files while others advise routing 3rd party API access through your own Web API ... and I am doing the latter. But I still need the Auth0 ClientSecret to get to my own Web API and I cannot figure out a better place way to get to it without storing them somewhere on the client-side.

One last-ditch solution I can think of is to not protect my Web API through Auth0 and instead every call from the client-side app to my Web API should include something unique (like the user ID from Auth0) that can be validated by the Web API. Thankfully, the user ID from Auth0 will be stored in our database when the user is set up initially, so this is actually possible.

Does Auth0 have any other way for me to get the Web API access token without providing the ClientSecret given that I already have the client-side app's access token? I am curious to know how others have secured both their client-side app and their Web API through Auth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you should not include the client secret in your client-side app. Do not use a client credentials flow, instead use a auth code + PKCE or implicit flow.

With that being said, Auth0 should handle most of that if you are using a library or SDK.

You have two options for getting the token:

- When requesting the initial access token and ID token add the Web API as an audience and request the related scopes.
- Make a silent request using the `checkSession` function for Auth0.js or `getTokenSilently` for auth0-spa-js

Take a look at this:
https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/part-3